# Mongoid Slug Localize migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid-slug

What's the best way to go about migrating Mongoid Slugs to localised versions. Missed adding `localise: true` on the slug field and now need to migrate my documents to have localised slugs.

eg: currently I have `_slugs:["my-slug"]`, when what I would like is `_slugs:{"en":"my-slug"}`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I wrote a rake task to do this which basically amounted to running the below in two separate tasks, running together inside the one block didn't work:

```
MyModel.all.each do |m|
  m.unset(:_slugs)
end

MyModel.all.each do |m|
  unit.set_slug! 
end
```

For what it's worth other examples of mongoid migrations can be found here: https://github.com/digitalplaywright/mongoid-slug/wiki/How-to-upgrade-to-1.0.0-or-newer